# How to floor/int in double using only SSE2?

Tags: c++, simd, truncate, intrinsics, sse2

In `float`, it seems pretty easy to `floor()` and than `int()`, such as:

```
float z = floor(LOG2EF * x + 0.5f);
const int32_t n = int32_t(z);
```

become:

```
__m128 z = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(log2ef, x), half);
__m128 t = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(_mm_cvttps_epi32(z));
z = _mm_sub_ps(t, _mm_and_ps(_mm_cmplt_ps(z, t), one));

__m128i n = _mm_cvtps_epi32(z);
```

But how would you achieve this in `double` using **only** SSE2?

This is the double version I'd like to convert:

```
double z = floor(LOG2E * x + 0.5);
const int32_t n = int32_t(z);
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just convert the double to an int?  You don't need floor at all.  (consider `int x = 5/2.0`)

Comment: @UKMonkey: https://github.com/dpiparo/vdt/blob/master/include/exp.h#L73

Comment: @markzzz Did you take a look [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4966&techs=SSE2) already? `_mm_cvttpd_epi32` appears to be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Question why do you need use intrinsic? Compiler doesn't do it for you if proper flags are set?

Comment: @MarekR no, it doesn't! And I'm learning...

Comment: Do you actually want `round(x)` (that is almost what `floor(x+0.5)` would give you)? Do you care about border cases? (Is `round(1.5)==round(2.5)` ok?) And do you want to have the result as `int32`, `int64` or `double`?

Comment: Also, if you want an integer result, what shall happen with overflows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the *double precision* equivalent (`...pd...`) of your *single precision* (`...ps...`) intrinsic:

```
__m128i n = _mm_cvtpd_epi32(z);
```

According to the Intel Intrinsics Guide, that intrinsic is indeed available for SSE2: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4966,1917&techs=SSE2

> `__m128i _mm_cvtpd_epi32 (__m128d a)`
>
> Convert packed double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements in `a` to packed 32-bit integers, and store the results in `dst`.
>
> ```
> FOR j := 0 to 1
>   i := 32*j
>   k := 64*j
>   dst[i+31:i] := Convert_FP64_To_Int32(a[k+63:k])
> ENDFOR
> ```

Comment: Uhm, but I'm in double. 64bit, not 32. It will loose precision, no?. _mm_cvtpd_epi64 doesn't exist for SSE2

Comment: Your question explicitly wants a `const int32_t`. That's what the `32` in the intrinsic name stands for. The **d**ouble **p**recision (64 bit floating point) is denoted by `pd`, as opposed to `ps` for **s**ingle **p**recision. Check out the intrinsic guide, it notes the involved data types very clearly. I also added a quote of the most relevant information to the answer for your convenience.

Comment: @markzzz and Max:  `cvtpd_epi32` uses the current rounding mode.  `cvttpd_epi32` uses truncation (toward 0).  Neither of these is `floor` (towards -Infinity).  So the question title is misleading, because you're actually asking about  `(int)floor(d + 0.5)` being used as a bad emulation of `(int)nearbyint(d)` or `lrint(d)`.

Comment: Also, @Mark's actual problem (in [How to convert scalar code of the double version of VDT's Pade Exp fast\_ex() approx into SSE2?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54364694)) wants the integers lined up with the doubles, so they can be shifted and stuffed into the exponent field of a `double` as part of implementing `exp()`.  So you'd need a `_mm_shuffle_epi32()` after this to create a vector of `[ 0,n2, 0,n1 ]`.  Unfortunately there's no way to get SSE2/AVX/anything to not shuffle the int32 elements to packed in the bottom of the vector.

Comment: More importantly, @mark's actual problem includes rounding a `double` to nearest integer, with the result as a `double`.  (Actually to get the fractional part, I think, by subtracting the integer part from the original (after some scaling?)).  Converting to integer and back will work, though, because in this case it only needs to work for small-magnitude doubles.  It's fine that doubles outside the -2^31 + 2^31-1 range will convert to integer values of `0x80000000` (INT_MIN).  But it's not fine for the general case, so this question should ask for everything you actually need + details.

Comment: @PeterCordes: you are actually right (as always :)). `(int)floor(d + 0.5)` seems what I'm after! Why bad emulation?